# Homology group of a topological n-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

Let M be an n dimensional topological manifold where $n \geq 0$ and $x \in M$. Then, $H_n(M,M \setminus \{ x\}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

I am familiar with singular homology and I already proved the claim for every $n \neq 1$ (by using excision).

I am having trouble proving the claim for $n=1$. I already proved that $H_1(M,M \setminus \{ x\}) \cong H_1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{S}^0)$  and I'm wondering how to prove that $H_1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{S}^0) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{S}^0= \{\pm1\}$ to finish the proof.

I also know that the sequence $H_1(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H_1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{S}^0) \rightarrow H_0(\mathbb{S}^0) \rightarrow H_0(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H_0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{S}^0)$ is exact-this is a part of the long exact sequence of the pair $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{S}^0)$-  and that $H_1(\mathbb{R}) \cong 0,H_0(\mathbb{S}^0) \cong \mathbb{Z } \oplus \mathbb{Z}, H_0(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ in case this can help.

Comment: You can use the long exact sequence of a pair of spaces

Comment: @MaximeRamzi A part of that sequence is $0 \rightarrow H_1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{S}^0) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb {Z}$. I don't see how I can use the exactness of that sequence to derive the asked isomorphism, can you elaborate more?

Comment: Well you know exactly what the morphism $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ is, don't you ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi What I know is that the map $H_0(\mathbb{S}^0) \rightarrow H_0(\mathbb{R})$ is the one induced by the inclusion $\mathbb{S}_0 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and that $H_0(\mathbb{S}^0) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, $H_0(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead the long exact sequence of reduced homology, which ends
$$H_1(\mathbb R) \mapsto H_1(\mathbb R,\mathbb S^0) \mapsto \widetilde H_0(\mathbb S^0) \mapsto \widetilde H_0(\mathbb R)
$$
Since $\text{rank}(\widetilde H_0(X)) = \text{rank}(H_0(X))-1$ for any $X$, the above sequence becomes
$$0 \mapsto H_1(\mathbb R,\mathbb S^0) \mapsto \mathbb Z \mapsto 0
$$
(You can also do it with the sequence in your question, if you work out the actual formulas for the homomorphisms).